# Output not working, receive an error

Tags: java, if-statement

For some reason, whenever I input one of the set colours in my code, it gives me an error. Can anyone see what the problem is here

This is my app class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class binCollectionAPP{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Declare Variables
        int apartmentNum, flag;
        String collect, binColour;

        //Objects
        binCollection bin = new binCollection();

        //Inputs
        apartmentNum=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your apartment number"));
        binColour=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the colour bin you are checking");

        //set
        bin.setApartNum(apartmentNum);
        bin.setBinColour(binColour);

        //compute
        bin.compute();

        //get
        collect=bin.getCollectDay();
        flag=bin.getFlag();

        //output
        if(flag == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, incorrect bin colour");
        }
        else if(flag == 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, incorrect apartment number");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your collection day is "+collect);
        }

    }
}
```

And my instantiable class is:

```
public class binCollection{
    //Declare Vars
    private int apartmentNum, flag;
    private String collect, binColour;

    //Constructor
    public binCollection(){
        apartmentNum = 0;
        flag = 0;
        collect = "";
        binColour = "";
    }

    //set methods
    public void setApartNum(int apartmentNum){
        this.apartmentNum = apartmentNum;
    }
    public void setBinColour(String binColour){
        this.binColour = binColour;
    }

    //compute
    public void compute(){
        if(apartmentNum % 2 == 0){
            if(binColour == "brown" || binColour == "Brown" ){
                collect = "Monday";
            }
            else if(binColour == "black"){
                collect = "Tuesday";
            }
            else if(binColour == "green"){
                collect = "Wednesday";
            }
            else{
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(apartmentNum % 2 == 1){
            if(binColour == "brown"){
                collect = "Tuesday";
            }
            else if(binColour == "black"){
                collect = "Wednesday";
            }
            else if(binColour == "green"){
                collect = "Thursday";
            }
            else{
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        else{
            flag = 2;
        }
    }

    //get methods
    public String getCollectDay(){
        return collect;
    }
    public int getFlag(){
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

About the error:
I am not receiving a compiler error, It all compiles and runs but on run and after inputting the apartment number and the colour "brown", then I receive the error (flag 2 in the code)

For "enter your apartment number" i enter 2 and for the colour, I have tried black and brown. All receiving the same error

Comment: include the error in your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not allowing me to upload an image of the error. However, the error i get is for not entering the correct bin colour

Comment: @CarlO'Beirne  you don't need to post an image of the error, just paste the error message within your post.

Comment: That is because we don't want images of errors.  We much prefer text of errors.  See: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @CarlO'Beirne - please add helpful information to your question instead of in comments.

Comment: I am not receiving a compiler error, It all compiles and runs but on run and after inputting the apartment number and the colour "brown", then I receive the error (flag 2)

Comment: Copy and paste your inputs and the error from your console into your question

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in how you check what the color is. In Java, String equality is done with the `.equals()` method (with `String`, `==` checks for physical equality, which is not what you want). Change your conditions to be

```
if (binColour.equals("brown") || binColour.equals("Brown")) {
    collect = "Monday";
}
```

Or, for even more simplicity, try using `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if (binColour.equalsIgnoreCase("brown")) {
    collect = "Monday";
}
```